# Generate valid representations of instances in time from ticks

Tags: c#, date, datetime, random

I am trying to generate random `DateTime` instances using the [DateTime Constructor (Int64)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) as below:

```
string date = new DateTime(ticks).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")
```

The `ticks` are random numbers between `633999744000000000` (2010/01/25 in ticks) and `635578272000000000` (2015/01/26 in ticks).

Output:

```
date       ticks
----       -----
13/37/2013 634963486624182148
27/58/2010 634158395314391599
20/49/2011 634442033950650720
21/15/2013 634943637106398216
10/30/2014 635380290170226984
10/07/2012 634881676490509687
27/43/2012 634711201999181055
15/13/2012 634726699845971038
01/59/2010 634241843691014848
```

However, the above results do not represent valid instances in time.

How can I generate random `DateTime` instances that represent *valid* dates using `ticks`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `DateTime` values are fine - it's your formatting that's wrong. You want `MM` rather than `mm` in your format string. `mm` is for *minutes*.

See ["custom date and time format strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) in MSDN for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Your format of the DateTime is wrong u need to use the format : "dd/MM/yyyy"

```
string date = new DateTime(ticks).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

---

[List of DateTime format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)